# Trying to make a for loop to draw an SVG in React

Tags: reactjs, loops, svg

Trying to make a for loop to draw an SVG in react...

I want to draw 4 circle in Svg by using loop

```
const circlex = 40;
  const circley = 40;

<svg>
<foreignObject
          className={classes.threeDotIcon}
          y="30" width="100" height="100"
        >
          {
            [1, 2, 3, 4].map((data, index) => {
              <svg width="100" height="100">
                <circle cx={circlex + 1} cy={circley + 1} r="30" stroke="black" fill="#caced5" />
              </svg>
            })
          }
        </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

I need When I Add Svg the circles auto draw in Svg....

Comment: Why would you use a foreignObject here?

Comment: Because Its Reusable.. I want to add image in circle during execution app

Answer (score 0):

Solved.....

```
<svg>
     {
      userInRoomLimit.map((data, i) => {
        return (
          <foreignObject
            className={classes.threeDotIcon}
            y='30'
            x={i * 70}
            width="100" height="100"
          >
            <svg width="100" height="100">
              <circle cx='40' cy='40' r="30" stroke="black" fill="#caced5" />
            </svg>
          </foreignObject>
        )
      })
    }
```